# Como faço para redirecionar o usuário para a pagína que o mesmo esta consultando, depois do login?

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs

Como faço para redirecionar o usuário para a página que o mesmo estava consultando, depois do usuário ter logado ? Já vi soluções utulizando o  $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];, mas creio não ser uma boa ideia, poderiam me ajudar com algum exemplo de código ?

Grato

Comment: É via ajax, modal ou ele sai de uma página e vai para `login.php`? Você quer que ele retorne para a origem do clique? Pode passar uma variável para o redirecionamento.

Comment: Estou tentando fazer via PHP .... nos casos que estou vendo o usuário eh direcionado para uma página espeifíca após o login. O que eu preciso eh que o usuário continue na página que ele estava navendo depois de logar. Ainda não consegui entender, pois o header('location:pagina.ext'); já especifica a página. Se por exemplo o usuário não estiver logado, escolha o produto que deseja comprar, clique no botao comprar e o site direcione para a página de login/cadastro. O que eu preciso eh que ele retorne a página de compra que estava antes de ser requerido o login.

Comment: "o site direcione para a página de login/cadastro. O que eu preciso eh que ele retorne a página de compra que estava antes de ser requerido o login." Bom ao meu ver tem uma confusão ai, se vc quer permitir ele escolher produtos sem logar, o login pode ser feito no final, agora que os parâmetros de escolha devem ir junto após o login aí é outros 500...

Answer (score 2):

Implemente o armazenamento da URL no seu processo. Exemplo:

- Enquanto o usário navega por estados públicos sem necessidade de sign-in, intercepte a URL atual e armazene-a em sessão ou *local storage*.
- Usuário navega para para um estado que requer login. Redirecione/trate.
- Quando o usuário retornar, obtenha a URL que você armazenou previamente e redirecione para o estado correspondente.

Comment: pra fazer essa armazenagem da URL há outra opção à: $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?

Comment: @FelipeLimaDiniz `HTTP_REFERER` é uma variável do servidor. A sugestão é que isto seja implementado client-side.

Answer (score 1):

Com o `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, você irá obter o `referrer` que foi definido pelo cabeçalho enviado, isto não é confiável, mas pode acreditar razoavelmente nele para essa finalidade. Você também pode utilizar um parâmetro no URL para indicar qual é aproxima página.

---

Um método utilizado para ambos os casos é utilizar o `?pagina=`, por exemplo o Twitter, o Instagram, o Facebook:

```
twitter.com/login?redirect_after_login=%2FInkeliz
```

```
instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=%2FInkeliz
```

```
facebook.com/login/?next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FInkeliz
```

Isso indica que após o login ele irá para onde o parâmetro indicar.

---

Dessa forma você pode ter um buttão, `<div class="fazerLogin">LOGIN</div>` e utiliza-lo para sempre adicionar o parametro, por exemplo:

```js
$('.fazerLogin').attr('href',
  'https://exemplo.com/login?next=' + encodeURIComponent($(location).attr('href'))
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="fazerLogin" href="https://exemplo.com/login">LOGIN</a>
```

*Coloque o mouse pro o "LOGIN" para ver o novo caminho do URL.*

Então no PHP faça o seguinte:

1. Obtenha o parâmetro `next`.
2. Verifique o `next` é válido, corresponde ao seu domínio.
3. Redirecione o usuário.

---

**Por exemplo:**

```
// Define um URL padrão se não houver um válido
function linkEncaminhar($nomeParametro){

    $url = 'https://exemplo.com/perfil';

     if(isLinkValido($nomeParametro) === true){
        $url = urldecode($_GET[$nomeParametro]);
     }

    return $url;

}

// Verifica se o URL é válido
function isLinkValido($nomeParametro){

    $meuDominio = 'https://exemplo.com/';

    return isset($_GET[$nomeParametro]) &&
           is_string($_GET[$nomeParametro]) &&
           substr( urldecode($_GET[$nomeParametro]) , 0, strlen($meuDominio)) === $meuDominio;

}
```

Dessa forma:

```
$urlRedicionar = linkEncaminhar('next');

header('Location: ' . $urlRedicionar);
```

Dessa forma se o `https://exemplo.com/login?next=https%3A%2F%2Fexemplo.com%2Fsobre-nos` for acessado após o login irá para `https://exemplo.com/sobre-nos`.

---

> **/!\ CUIDADO:**
>
> Se houver um link do tipo `https://exemplo.com/configuracao?excluir_conta=true` sem qualquer tipo de *CSRF-Token*, uma pessoa pode fazer um `https://exemplo.com/login?next=https://exemplo.com/configuracao?excluir_conta=true`, daí após a pessoa conectar e será redirecionada para tal URL, que vai fazer excluir a conta, nessa situação hipotética!

<sub>Existe um problema desse tipo num site estatal "bem famoso"...</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar `header('location:pagina.ext');`

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda! Tem algum exemplo de código ?

Comment: Poxa campeão, o exemplo vem geralmente de um código inicial do AP, no link da duplicada tem...

Comment: O cabeçalho só contém a URI do recurso. Parâmetros como *querystrings* e estados (`#ancora`) são ignorados.

Comment: Não entendi man...Na verdade eu entendi, mas qual a relação com a minha resposta ?